# Matlab is continuously asking me to activate when I am trying to launch

Tags: installation, matlab

Matlab is continuously asking me to activate when I am trying to launch

```
cd /usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/bin

User@User-Inspiron-N5010:/usr/local/MATLAB/R2014a/bin$ sudo ./matlab
```

What is the solution for this problem ?

Am I supposed to get a new license file?

Comment: How many users does your OS has?

Comment: @syrux Just one

Comment: Are you the administrator of the PC?

Comment: Any luck with it? I'm facing the same problem. It keeps saying that activation is successful, then the next time I click on matlab I need to go through the whole process again.